# How can I smooth these lumps and bumps, to match with that of the surrounding surface?

Tags: modeling, sculpting, smooth

I am trying to get rid of these creases, lumps and bumps so the result is a continuous smooth surface.
[image]

I have looked at so many different ways to smooth and flatten, but so far this is the best I have managed (with much experimentation).
[image]

Is there an easy way to remove this crease and create a smooth surface?

Apologies for the poor description, I don't really know how else to explain what I need - hopefully you'll get the jist.
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to use a *Cast* modifier. Setting it up will be a bit tricky, though. You will need an empty object to define the center axis of the cylinder which is going to be the Z-axis of the empty. You will also need a vertex group on your geometry to limit the effect of the modifier to the area you want to fix. Your modifier should look like this:

[image: Cast]

You will need to adjust the *Radius* to match the radius of your cylinder. I called the vertex group *Cast*. You need to assign the vertices you want to fix to it. The empty object should be placed along the center axis of the shape with its Z-axis aligned with it.